# Get values from form in modal and put them into table row using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do this simple thing but I need to avoid using anything but html, css and plain javaScript.

I have modal with Name text box and one drop down menu. 
On the main page I have html table with 3 columns: Date Created, Name and Tests.

When I click button Add new on the top of the page, modal pops up and I want to be able to enter values in form controls, click Save button and show those values in my table.

I know how to do this by using jQuery or other more modern technologies, but it's not allowed. So I need help with getting back to basics.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Battery Test App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<button id="btnAddNew">Add new</button>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Date Created</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Tests</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="modalAddNewTest" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <form name="formTestInfo" method="post">
      Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="tbName">
        <p id="nameVal"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      Test:<br>
        <select>
          <option value="belbin">Belbin</option>
          <option value="raven">Raven</option>
          <option value="ppa">PPA</option>
          <option value="ppaPlus">PPA+</option>
          <option value="basicKnowledge">Basic Knowledge</option>
          <option value="pct">PCT</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
        <button id="btnSave" onclick="validateForm()">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var nameValidation;
  var modal = document.getElementById('modalAddNewTest');
  var btn = document.getElementById("btnAddNew");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }

  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["formTestInfo"]["tbName"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        nameValidation = "Name must be filled out";
        document.getElementById("nameVal").innerHTML = nameValidation;
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an id to the table

```
<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Date Created</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Tests</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now in your validateForm function you are checking if the form is valid.Once the form is valid assign the values entered in inputs of the form to the table as follows.

```
     function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["formTestInfo"]["tbName"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            nameValidation = "Name must be filled out";
            document.getElementById("nameVal").innerHTML = nameValidation;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

         //In the first step using InsertRow function you are creating a first row i.e tr 
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

        //In the second step you create a cell i.e td dynamically
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

        // Here in step 3 you can add data to your cells from the modal popup inputs(According to your logic)
        cell1.innerHTML = "Your Date Created";
        cell2.innerHTML = "Your name data from modal";
        cell3.innerHTML = "Your Test data from modal";
        }
    }
```

To avoid postback mention the type of button as button as below

```
<button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="validateForm()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Yeah I had similar idea, but the problem was that when I click add button nothing is added to table. Modal disappears and when I use debug I see that I have no exceptions, all values are correct, debug pass creation of new row and add values, but on page nothing... @bhanu.cs

Comment: Is your page getting a full page postback on click of add button?

Comment: Well I've didn't define it... Only if it's like that by default. I was trying adding return false; but it didnt help... @bhanu.cs

Comment: No it not by default for a button tag..Recheck if some other issues are causing your page postback.

Comment: Yeah got it.Mention the type of button as button like suggesedt in the edit of the answer

Comment: Thats it. Thank you! :D

Comment: Good to hear that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a table with the required number of columns in the form. on clicking save using the table id u can insert rows

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");


var row = table.insertRow(0);


var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
var col2 = row.insertCell(1);


col1.innerHTML = "Content to be added";
col2.innerHTML = "Content to be added";
```